# Automatically convert users display name to first_name and last_name in wordpress user_meta table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have imported a user database into a new wordpress website, in the display_name field it currently contains the users first name and last name.

I've now noticed that there is no data for all the new users in the user_meta table, I am wondering if there is any quick SQL solution to get the users ID, display name and then add it to first name last name in the user_meta table.

The display name is firstname lastname, so would need to split them into first name and last name

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. Include display names like Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies.

Comment: Patching your database after import is a pain in the xxx neck.  @jarlh mentioned some of the nasty edge cases. Any chance you can repeat your import, perhaps with a better import tool or with more complete data.